# Cant copy files into USB stick. USB stick is Read only

Tags: 14.04, usb, permissions

Ok so when I do sudo `fdisk -l`, I get this:

```
Disco /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 121601 cilindros, 1953525168 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x5a4bf8f6

Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
La partición 1 no se inició en el limite físico del sector

# This is the USB
Disco /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32015679488 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 3892 cilindros, 62530624 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0xc1ceab04

Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sdb1   *          63    62524979    31262458+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Then, I do

```
 sudo chmod 777 /dev/sdb
```

But I still get the error that says that the USB drive is "Read Only".

**Edit**

When I do `mount` I get this:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/alejandro/Gladiador type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: What is the output of `mount ` with the USB stick in?

Comment: I'll add it as an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the permissions of the `/media/$your_user_name` folder.

It should be owned by you and your user should have all permissions (Read, Write, eXecute).

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/$USER
sudo chmod u+rwx /media/$USER
```

Also check the permissions on the folder of the mountpoint (Gladiador in your case).

I could not find an existing answer, but I think this was a common issue in 14.04 with some permissions missing in `/media`.